# Funcao SQL Server - Feriados

Tags: sql, query, funções, sql-server-2012

Boa tarde!

Prezados, tenho a seguinte função abaixo que é dos dias não trabalhados que está vindo somente o sabado e domingo, porém, queria que nessa função fosse incluída os feriados. OBS: Já tenho uma funçao de feriados, porém, queria incluir essa funcao de feriados para dentro da função de dias não trabalhados. Abaixo, segue as duas funções.

```
-> FUNÇÃO DIA NÃO TRABALHADO

USE [0800net_PRD]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[FN_DIA_NAO_TRAB]    Script Date: 12/09/2017 17:19:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/*
Função para verificar se a data informada é um dia útil
SELECT dbo.FN_DIA_NAO_TRAB ('2016-01-01')
*/

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_DIA_NAO_TRAB]
 (
 @data SMALLDATETIME
 )
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @num TINYINT
 DECLARE @flgDataNaoUtil BIT

 IF DATENAME(dw, @data) IN ('Domingo', 'Sábado')
 BEGIN
 SET @num = 1
 END

 IF @num > 0
 BEGIN
 SET @flgDataNaoUtil = 1
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
 SET @flgDataNaoUtil = 0
 END

 RETURN @flgDataNaoUtil

END

-> FUNÇÃO FERIADOS

USE [0800net_PRD]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[getFeriados]    Script Date: 12/09/2017 17:24:35 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[getFeriados](@ano int = null)
RETURNS @feriado TABLE (dia DATETIME, feriado varchar(100))
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pascoa SMALLDATETIME,
    @dia int ,@mes int , @anoPascoa int ;

    IF(@ano IS NULL) BEGIN 
        set  @ano  =  DATEPART(year, GETDATE());
    END 

    SET @pascoa = dbo.getDataPascoa(@ano);
    SET @dia = DATEPART(DAY, @pascoa);
    SET @mes =  DATEPART(MONTH, @pascoa);
    SET @anoPascoa = DATEPART(YEAR, @pascoa);

    INSERT INTO @feriado (dia, feriado) VALUES(@pascoa, 'Pascoa');
    INSERT INTO @feriado (dia, feriado) VALUES(CAST('1-1-' + CAST(@anoPascoa AS VARCHAR) + ' 00:00:00' AS DATETIME), 'Confraternização Universal');
    INSERT INTO @feriado (dia, feriado) VALUES(CAST(CAST(@anoPascoa AS VARCHAR) + '-4-21' AS DATETIME), 'Tiradentes');
    INSERT INTO @feriado (dia, feriado) VALUES(CAST(CAST(@anoPascoa AS VARCHAR) + '-5-1' AS DATETIME), 'Dia do Trabalhador');
    INSERT INTO @feriado (dia, feriado) VALUES(CAST(CAST(@anoPascoa AS VARCHAR) + '-7-9' AS DATETIME), 'Dia da Independência');
    INSERT INTO @feriado (dia, feriado) VALUES(CAST(CAST(@anoPascoa AS VARCHAR) + '-10-12' AS DATETIME), 'N. S. Aparecida');
    INSERT INTO @feriado (dia, feriado) VALUES(CAST(CAST(@anoPascoa AS VARCHAR) + '-11-2' AS DATETIME), 'Todos os santos');
    INSERT INTO @feriado (dia, feriado) VALUES(CAST(CAST(@anoPascoa AS VARCHAR) + '-11-15' AS DATETIME), 'Proclamação da republica');
    INSERT INTO @feriado (dia, feriado) VALUES(CAST(CAST(@anoPascoa AS VARCHAR) + '-12-25' AS DATETIME), 'Natal');
    INSERT INTO @feriado (dia, feriado) VALUES(DATEADD(DAY, 60, @pascoa), 'Corpus Christi');
    INSERT INTO @feriado (dia, feriado) VALUES(DATEADD(DAY, -2, @pascoa), '6º feira Santa');
    INSERT INTO @feriado (dia, feriado) VALUES(DATEADD(DAY, -47, @pascoa), '3º feria Carnaval');
    INSERT INTO @feriado (dia, feriado) VALUES(DATEADD(DAY, -48, @pascoa), '2º feria Carnaval');

     RETURN;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua função de feriados não está muito legal por vários motivos, porém vou me focar na sua função principal. Em primeiro lugar vou alterar o nome, removendo o `nao` que pode causa confusão.

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fn_dia_trabalhado(@data DATE)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @resultado BIT;

  IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @data) IN (7, 1) OR EXISTS(SELECT 1
                                                    FROM getferiados(DATEPART(YEAR, @data)) f
                                                   WHERE CAST(f.dia AS DATE) = @data)
  BEGIN
    SET @resultado = 0;
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    SET @resultado = 1;
  END;

  RETURN @resultado;
END;
GO
```

Após todas as alterações teríamos a função acima que irá retornar 1 se o dia for trabalhado e 0 se não for.

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo usando a function que já existe.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_DIA_NAO_TRAB] ( @data SMALLDATETIME ) RETURNS BIT AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @diaNaoTrab TINYINT DECLARE @flgDataNaoUtil BIT
    SET @diaNaoTrab= 0 

    IF DATENAME(dw, @data) IN ('Domingo', 'Sábado') 
    BEGIN 
        SET @diaNaoTrab = 1 
    END

    IF EXISTS( SELECT NULL FROM getFeriados(year(@data)) WHERE dia=@data )
    BEGIN 
        SET @diaNaoTrab = 1 
    END


    RETURN @diaNaoTrab

END
```

OBS: Não é uma boa pratica escrever metodos ou functions com uma negativa no nome, pois torna um pouco mais confuso o seu entendimento.

Comment: @Renan-Bessa você conseguiu ?

Comment: ,assim,a função executou sem nenhum erro, mas, quero aplicar essa função na consulta, porém, na consulta da o seguinte erro. "A conversão de um tipo de dados varchar em um tipo de dados smalldatetime resultou em um valor fora do intervalo" e esse erro ocorreu depois da alteração da função.

Comment: Você deve estar  passado a data em um varchar em um formato diferente do padrão de data do seu banco de dados. Geralmente é 'yyyy-MM-dd'